# Jhipster Jwt Authentication for Mobile API

Tags: android, authentication, jwt, jhipster

I have a jHipster project with Jwt Authentication but I can't get it to work outside de webapp. I'm currently developping a Android application and the authentication process get harder than I expected.

Basically I'm sending the parameters of the LoginDTO, to UserJwtController#authorize ('/api/authenticate'). At first I was getting Unauthorized, both on Android or Postman (I'm using it to test the requests). 
If I change the '/api' to permitAll, I'm getting 405, Request method 'POST' not supported.

EDIT

It was a wrong typo on Android :/

Answer (score 1):

It works fine for me against `/api/authenticate`, so either you use wrong URL (e.g. `/api/authorize`) or your JSON payload is wrong. The only issue you could have is with CORS. You should consider testing with `curl` as it is easier than PostMan for reporting here what you really do and also the curl options are already built for you in JHipster swagger page.